# Why can't a parameter of function type take an argument whose parameters implement the original parameter's interface?

Tags: typescript

Okay so the title is weird.  But it seems strange that you can't pass a function which takes a type which implements the interface the passed-in function is supposed to take:

```
interface Empty { }

class Implements implements Empty {
    constructor(public s: string) {}
}

type TakesEmpty = (e: Empty) => void;

function TakesImplementor(e: Implements): void {}

function f(t: TakesEmpty) { }

/*
  Argument of type '(e: Implements) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakesEmpty'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'e' are incompatible. Property 's' is missing in type 'Empty' but required in type 'Implements'.
*/
f(TakesImplementor);

// But this works
function te (e: Empty): void {}
te(new Implements(""));
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOYCeyDeyAvgFAkIA2cAztcgJJYUToTh3BMtth0bZ58JZCOQIA9iGpgoAVwRhxUABSZZAIwrAEyagC5dM0AHMAlAVKkSuTCgAqcANYRq-XMgC8yZRANuc5h4AfMgAbuLAACYA3GQwsiAKwJLIDs7UjJjMrOBKPgaZ2TzUpgbhURZxCUkpMMpgBmku-uaEVnVNGVw5ilCmsSTxiWDJIMiQ3r5oWLilYRGRlZDKIBAA7gzdxcoARDum-WRAA)

Why is this the case?

Comment: Disable `--strictFunctionTypes`, the implementation isn't compatible with the type. See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your example code nothing bad will actually happen at runtime because the functions don't do anything at all.  But given the signature of `TakesImplementor()`, it could be implemented like this:

```
function TakesImplementor(e: Implements): void {
    console.log(e.s.toUpperCase());
}
```

That's fine, right?  `TakesImplementor()` accepts a parameter named `e` of type `Implements`, which has an `s` property of type `string`.  Inside `TakesImplementor()` you can access `e.s.toUpperCase()`.

And then, given the signature of `f()`, it could be implemented like this:

```
function f(t: TakesEmpty) {
    t({});
}
```

That's also fine, right?  The `t` parameter passed into `f()` is itself a function of the type `TakesEmpty`, meaning you should be able to call `t({})`, since the object `{}` is a valid `Empty`.

Yep, everything great until you go ahead and run this:

```
f(TakesImplementor);
```

And it explodes at runtime.  `f(TakesImplementor)` calls `TakesImplementor({})`, which calls `{}.s.toUpperCase()`, which doesn't exist because `{}.s` is undefined.  Boom. *That* is why the line `f(TakesImplementor)` gives an error message:

```
// Property 's' is missing in type 'Empty' but required in type 'Implements'.
```

`TakesImplementor` is not a `TakesEmpty`, because `TakesImplementor` only accepts `Implements` types, while `TakesEmpty` is required to accept all `Empty` types, not just `Implements` types.

---

It might be counterintuitive, but when dealing with functions, you *narrow* its type when you *widen* the type of its parameters, and you *widen* its type when you *narrow* the type of its parameters.  This "going-the-other-way" of function parameters is known as [*contravariance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types).  They vary in the opposite way, or "contra-vary". (This is as opposed to function *return* types, which widen the function type when widened and narrow the function type when narrowed... they vary together, or "co-vary", and thus are *covariant*.)

By narrowing the parameter type of `TakesImplementor` from `Empty` to `Implements`, you have *widened* the type of `TakesImplementor` itself compared to `TakesEmpty`.  Every `TakesEmpty` can be used in place of `TakesImplementor`, but not vice versa.  Contravariant.

Contravariance of function parameter types is enforced in TypeScript 2.6 and above when you use the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) (also enabled with just `--strict`).  It's generally a good thing to enforce.

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOYCeyDeyAvgFAkIA2cAztcgJJYUToTh3BMtth0bZ58JZCOQIA9iGpgoAVwRhxUABSZZAIwrAEyagC5dM0AHMAlAWIlSJXJhQAVOAGsI1frmQBeZMogH3OOaeAHzIAG7iwAAmANxkMLIgCsCSyI4u1IyYzKzgSr4GWTk81KYGEdEEwqISUuLMAHQU4sa+DdQNigCqmHZQAMI0EMqmpnGkCUlgKSDIMMpgBumuAeZCoshgyvhEY1Yk88uZXLmKUHtkQA)