# Why is typescript not able to infer the correct indexed type here?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following type to extract all keys `K` from some type `T` where `T[K]` is of type `V`:

```
type KeysOfFieldsOfType<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

Now, consider the following function:

```
const Func = <Data, DataKey extends KeysOfFieldsOfType<Data, string>>(k: DataKey) => {
    const x: Data[DataKey] = "xyz"
}
```

I would expect that since `DataKey` can only be a key such that its corresponding value is of type `string`, typescript should be able to infer that inside of that method, the type `Data[DataKey]` has to equal `string`. Apparently this is not the case and the initialization of `x` does not compile with the error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Data[DataKey]'.

Why is it not assignable? In what scenario can `Data[DataKey]` be anything else then `string` in this situation?

This is a simplified example of what I tried to do in the first place - consider the following interface definition:

```
interface I<T, K extends KeysOfPropsOfType<T, V>, V extends T[K]> {
    key: K,
    value: V
}
```

instead of only string properties I want to allow any properties of type `V`. Some trial and error lead me to this "circular" kind of definition where I restrict `V`with `K`and vice versa (I wonder Why this even works, but this is probably an other question).
Given some interface `Thing` which actually has some `string` property, we can for example define the following type:

```
type W<K extends KeysOfPropsOfType<Thing, string>> = I<Thing, K, string>
```

But allowing some arbitrary type does not work - This:

```
type U<T, K extends KeysOfPropsOfType<T, string>> = I<T, K, T[K]>
```

does not compile.

What happens here exactly and why? And how can I construct the desired behaviour?

Comment: Note that `Func<{ x: "hello" }, "x">("x");` is a valid call of `Func`, but you are erroneously trying to assign `"xyz"` to a variable of type `"hello"` in the function.   There are types narrower than `string`.  Presumably you want keys which `string` is assignable *from* and not *to*, but even that won't work inside a function with an unresolved generic type. 

I'm a bit confused about your "desired behavior" since as it stands your types and functions all require manual generic type parameter specification... they all seem to have too many type parameters to be inferred anywhere.

Comment: My problem with your example code is that you're not motivating the constraints... `T` is mostly just floating around.  Instead of trying to do a `KeysMatching<T, string>` (or `KeysOfFieldPropThingsOfType` or whatever you're calling it) I'd constrain `T` to `Record<K, string>` or even dispense with `T` and write `Record<K, string>` directly.  And `V` seems unnecessary since `T[K]` should be `V`.  I can't imagine introducing  `T` and `K` and `V` as three separate type parameters without seeing some use cases that motivate it.  Could you provide some motivating example code?

Comment: As it stands, [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8j5N) is what the code collapses to if I remove unmotivated type parameters.

Comment: Some of what you're running into is likely the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140126/parameter-type-that-a-generic-type-is-passed-to-isnt-resolved-as-expected)